# Immutablejs: One liner code to convert keys of a map into array?

Tags: javascript, immutable.js

From the docs: [Map#keys](http://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/Map/keys)

I get the keys of a Map and loop through it to transform them into an array. Is there a one line code to cleanly convert these keys into an array?

Comment: Can you show your current implementation?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You can use [`keySeq`](http://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/Map/keySeq) instead of `keys`, an `IndexedSeq` has `toArray` method:

```
var map = Immutable.fromJS({
  a: 1,
  b: 2,
  c: {
    d: "asdf"
  }
})

var arr = map.keySeq().toArray()
```

Answer (score 8):

If you can use ES6:

```
var map = Immutable.fromJS({
  a: 1,
  b: 2,
  c: {
    d: "asdf"
  }
});

var [...arr] = map.keys();
console.log(arr); // ["a", "b", "c"]
```

Or

```
var arr = Array.from(map.keys());
console.log(arr); // ["a", "b", "c"]
```

Comment: Nice, this is cleaner.

Comment: A quick mesurement with a small map showed that keySeq is about twice as fast. (Immutable.js 3)